# Programatically add Append-Only Comments to Sharepoint List Item

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm hoping to be able to append to the V3Comments (Append-Only Comments) column on a Sharepoint list item programmatically using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.

I'm using a sequence similar to:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("path_to_site"))
{
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list_name");

    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    ListItemCollection list_items = list.GetItems(query);
    context.Load(list_items);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    ListItem list_item = list_items[0];

    list_item["V3Comments"] = "New comment.";
    list_item.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

When I attempt to do this, the following InnerException is thrown:

> Field or property "AttachmentFiles" does not exist.

Any pointers on what I need to get this working would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list I am using had attachments enabled (despite not actually being used). After disabling the attachments, and leaving it for some time, it works as intended.

I wish I could explain the reason for this, but it would be pure speculation.

I've no idea how this would be done for a list with attachments.